# knapsack() vector length issues

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, knapsack-problem

When I run

```
weights <- 1:50
profits <- 1:50
library(adagio)
knapsack(w = weights, p = profits, cap = 30)
```

I get the error

```
Error in F[, k] <- G : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
In addition: Warning message:
In pmax(G, H) : an argument will be fractionally recycled
```

but when I run smaller sized vectors, like

```
weights <- 1:20
profits <- 1:20
knapsack(w = weights, p = profits, cap = 30)
```

it runs fine. Does knapsack() just slow down (and prevent running) for larger sets? I'm looking to use lengths in the thousands eventually.

Comment: Does the `cap = 30` have something to do with it ?  When I changed `cap=30` to `cap=60` the error went away.  However, that doesn't mean this is the correct solution.

Comment: weird, 10,20,40 have the same result. cap = 50, 60, 70 give results.

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue though, it's unclear to me why this is happening, and if it can be avoided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with passing elements with weight exceeding the total capacity. To see the issue, let's look at the first few lines of the `knapsack` function:

```
function (w, p, cap) 
{
    n <- length(w)
    x <- logical(n)
    F <- matrix(0, nrow = cap + 1, ncol = n)
    G <- matrix(0, nrow = cap + 1, ncol = 1)
    for (k in 1:n) {
        F[, k] <- G
        H <- c(numeric(w[k]), G[1:(cap + 1 - w[k]), 1] + p[k])
        G <- pmax(G, H)
    }
```

When iteratively filling the `F` matrix one column at a time, the algorithm creates a vector `H` with the following command (and then immediately computing `pmax(G, H)`):

```
H <- c(numeric(w[k]), G[1:(cap + 1 - w[k]), 1] + p[k])
```

`numeric(w[k])` has length `w[k]`, and when `w[k] <= cap`, `G[1:(cap + 1 - w[k]), 1] + p[k]` has length `cap + 1 - w[k]`, meaning the entire vector `H` has length `cap+1`, matching the size of `G`. On the other hand, when `w[k] == cap + 1` we will end up with an `H` vector of size `cap+2`, which doesn't match the size of `G` and gives us trouble, and with `w[k] > cap + 1` we will get an error for mixing positive and negative indices.

Getting back to your example function call, you have weights up to 50 but only a capacity of 30, yielding an error:

```
weights <- 1:50
profits <- 1:50
knapsack(w = weights, p = profits, cap = 30)
# Error in F[, k] <- G : 
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
# In addition: Warning message:
# In pmax(G, H) : an argument will be fractionally recycled
```

However when you limit to elements with weight not exceeding the capacity, you get no errors:

```
knapsack(w = weights[weights <= 30], p = profits[weights <= 30], cap = 30)
# $capacity
# [1] 30
# 
# $profit
# [1] 30
# 
# $indices
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7 8
```

It would be most ideal if the `knapsack` function gracefully removed any object with weight exceeding the capacity (since no such elements could ever be used in a feasible solution) and gave you a solution for the code you posted, but as a workaround you could simply remove them yourself from the input to the `knapsack` function.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error (which is how I got this SO post..)  I think that the adagio knapsack function doesn't like profits or weights that are fractional values.  I used rnorm() to generate profits and weights, to compare their results to another knapsack function that I personally wrote.  Even with a capacity that was several times larger than all the weights put together, I was getting the 'recycling' error.  However when I rounded off the rnorm() vectors before passing them as arguments to knapsack, no problems.